# How to arrange a bootstrap inline-form to the right of a table that changes dynamically with window size?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table and an inline-form, which are next to each other using `float: left;` on both. However, when I resize my browser the form will be pushed down below the table even when there is a lot of blank space to the right. Here are the classes for my inline-form:

```
<div class="submission">
    <form action="/funds" method="post" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <select name="group" class="custom-select">
                <option disabled selected value="">Select an option</option>
                {% for group in groups %}
                    <option value="{{ group }}">{{ group }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-4 mb-2">
            <input type="text" name="amt" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <input type="submit" value="Update Funds" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the styles.css for my form div:

```
.submission {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10vh;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}
```

This is how it looks when the screen is big enough:
[image: Proper Layout]

However, past a certain point, it will go below the table, even with quite a bit of space on the right:
[image: Blank space on the right]

Is it possible to make it stack vertically and only move below the table if it is not possible for it to be stacked on the right?

Comment: What's the problem? the table or the from? you show codes of your select form.

Comment: @Newbee the problem is that the form moves down instead of squeezes into the right side but i want it to be on the right while it is possible